# generating huge Boost.MPL type sequences

Tags: c++, boost-mpl, template-meta-programming

Consider the following code that automates generation of Boost.MPL type sequences (list or vector).

```
    #include <iostream>                     // cout
    #include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>       // for_each
    #include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>       // identity, make_identity
    #include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>            // int_
    #include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>           // list
    #include <boost/mpl/next.hpp>           // next
    #include <boost/mpl/push_front.hpp>     // push_front
    #include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>         // vector

    template<size_t, typename> struct iota_n;

    template<typename Value>
    struct iota_n<0, Value>
    :
            boost::mpl::list<>      // can change this to boost::mpl::vector<>
    {};

    template<size_t N, typename Value>
    struct iota_n
    :
            boost::mpl::push_front< typename
                    iota_n< 
                            N - 1, typename
                            boost::mpl::next<Value>::type
                    >::type,
                    Value
            >
    {};

    // works for N <=  20 and boost::mpl::vector
    // works for N <= 247 and boost::mpl::list
    typedef iota_n< 247, boost::mpl::int_<0> >::type sequence;

    struct print
    {
            template<typename T>
            void operator()(boost::mpl::identity<T>)
            {
                    std::cout << T::value << "\n";
            }
    };

    int main()
    {
            boost::mpl::for_each<sequence, boost::mpl::make_identity<> >(
                    print()
            );
            std::cout << BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE << '\n';         // 20 on my system
            std::cout << BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE << '\n';       // 20 on my system
            return 0;
    }
```

According to the Boost.MPL documentation, a `boost::mpl::list` sequence can have up to `BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE` elements, and similarly for a `boost::mpl::vector` the compiler can go up to `BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE`. Both macros evaluate to 20 on my system.

MSVC++ 2010 and Boost 1.47.0 indeed cannot generate vectors with more than the documented 20 elements. What is surprising that it can, however, generate lists with up to 247 elements!

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Just a guess but I'd think it's more difficult and involves more metaprogramming to implement an mpl vector than a linked list which can just consist of a simple two parameter template. It's not too surprising to me that mpl lists would be capable of handling more elements given the simpler templates and possibly fewer instantiations, less static recursion, and branching.

Comment: Then in that case, why aren't the macros for limiting vector and list sequence different? On my system, both are 20, yet I can generate lists of up to 247 elements!

Comment: Those macros place practical limits probably based on what boost authors can generally support safely across a wide range of compilers. The fact that you can go over with list is probably still going beyond what the boost authors would like you to do to write portable code.

Comment: In other words, you might be able to do 247 list entries with your mpl list on whatever compiler you happen to be using now (MSVC 2010), but you probably won't be able to port that code to many different compilers. Each one has different limits, and those macros are probably based on practical limits the authors found across various compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/variadic-sequence.html), `BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_xxx_SIZE` specifies the limit for the sequence's *variadic* form (e.g. `list<>`); the *numbered* form (e.g. `list42<>`), has no predefined top limit, aside from compiler limitations on the number of template parameters. Okay, the latter statement is not completely accurate: in practice, in the default library configuration, *there is* a limit on the numbered forms imposed by using pre-generated preprocessed headers; see [this post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2004/08/70900.php) on how to lift it.

FOLLOW UP: @rhalbersma You seem to be bundling together two separate notions: the maximum number of list elements vs. the maximum arity of the `list`'s "constructor". `BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE` [controls the latter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/limit-list-size.html), not the former, and there is really no dependency between the two. Your code above is testing the former; maximum template arity is a totally different beast.

The reason there is an arity limit for MPL sequences in the first place is that the library had to emulate variadic templates (it was written way before C++11), which is typically done [by defaulting unused arguments to some auxiliary type and providing a bunch of specializations to weed out those unused arguments before constructing the actual sequence](http://www.generic-programming.org/~dgregor/cpp/variadic-templates.pdf). The cost of this is that the default arguments typically show up in error messages and obscure everything else, and a large number of specializations has noticeable effect on compilation times. IOW, you had to stop somewhere, and at the time it seemed unlikely that you'd often need to pass more than 20 sequence elements to a sequence's "constructor" (and if you did, there are always numbered forms), hence the current limits.

Comment: Yes, I know how to change the limit macros. However, on my system, the macro for list is equal to 20, yet I can generate lists with up to 247 elements! And the error message for iota_n<248, ...> mentions a Sequence = list<...>, not a list248<...>. So I'm still puzzled why the macro does not limit the list to 20, as it does with vector<>.

Comment: @rhalbersma Ever tried porting your code to different compilers? Those limits you are seeing now aren't based on some standard language limitation but a limitation of compilers. Pushing the template recursion limits of your compiler is definitely not going to produce very portable code.

Comment: @stinky472 I used to have a parallel build with Eclipse/CDT (using both the gcc and Intel compilers) but Ubuntu was lagging a bit in the C++ libraries (I make heavy use of c++11 features in my project). I should retry, thanks.

Comment: I just saw the FOLLOW UP (I didn't get automatically notified because it was not a separate comment). Thanks, that's a really helpful answer.